# How to create localization with react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I'm making a localization for react native and here is what I made so far

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { Platform, NativeModules } from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const languageJson = require('../../language.json')

const deviceLanguage =
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale
        : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier

export const LanguageContext = React.createContext(deviceLanguage)

export const T = ({ children }) => {
    const { language } = useContext(LanguageContext)
    if (!children) return ''
    let res =
        languageJson[children] && languageJson[children][language]
            ? languageJson[children][language]
            : languageJson[children]['en_US']
    return res
}

export const t = string =>
    languageJson[string] && languageJson[string][deviceLanguage]
        ? languageJson[string][deviceLanguage]
        : languageJson[string]['en_US']

export default function Language({ children }) {
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState(deviceLanguage)

    const t = key => {
        let string =
            languageJson[key] && languageJson[key][language]
                ? languageJson[key][language]
                : languageJson[key]['en_US']

        if (string) return string
        throw Error(`Key ${key} not found`)
    }

    return (
        <LanguageContext.Provider value={{ language, setLanguage, t }}>
            {children}
        </LanguageContext.Provider>
    )
}

Language.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
}
```

So in this code, I read a json file and get the device language to read the strings.

As I'm using a context to pass the device language but that is where the problem starts.

In some cases, I need the a string but it isn't inside a component, so I made the function `t` (that is outside the component), but when the `language` changes, `t` won't change, because it isn't in the context and I also can't use context in a function that isn't a react component.

How can I implement this `t` function, that will be able to see the changes of the device language, but also work together with the context?

Comment: I suggest to use the well known 3rd party library `react-intl` for localization of React applications. It is working also in React native apps. https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md#react-native

Comment: Are you solve it?

Comment: @OliverD not yet, kind of stopped looking for it, sorry

Comment: I wrote a blog post targeting localization in React Native - however, I did not use context API - instead, i just added current localization to the top component in the app by using useSelector / mapStateToProps / connecting to the Redux store.

Here is link:
https://stefan-majiros.com/blog/implementing-react-native-localization-like-a-pro/

Answer (score 0):

In react native node package available for localisation

https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n

example :

```js
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';

I18n.t('name');
```

Comment: sorry, this doesn't answer my question and this package is deprecated